# Does it mean anything when the camera screen turns orange to take a pic?

Tags: far-cry-3

In Far Cry 3, when taking a picture sometimes the screen turns orange and the same sound is heard as when a relic is picked up. Does this have any meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some missions where you have to take pictures of certain objects. The orange color shows you that you have this object in sight, and the jingle tells you that you just completed a mission objective.