# Inability to capture image at this certain location in Far Cry 3

Tags: far-cry-3

While playing Far Cry 3, I tried to use my camera inside the boat (mission "**Get aboard the ship**" or similar title). When I pressed <kbd>Z</kbd> on the following place, instead of normal blue coloured grid, I was surprised to see a yellow one. Not only this, the click sound was a little different as well.

[image: Aboard the ship]

<sub>Click to view actual image</sub>

I was not able to grab a screenshot at that moment, but I did encounter a similar behaviour later on:

Normal behaviour

> [image: normal behaviour]
>
> <sub>Click to view actual image</sub>

Weird things happened on moving the mouse just a little to left:

> [image: weird]
>
> <sub>Click to view actual image</sub>

Does this have any significance? Anyone here knows about it?

Comment: Might be related to [Does it mean anything when the camera screen turns orange to take a pic?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97862/does-it-mean-anything-when-the-camera-screen-turns-orange-to-take-a-pic/97940#97940). It usually behaves that way on side-missions where you have to take photos of things to indicate you are pointing at the correct object. Maybe there is a side-mission photography target there which is invisible because the mission isn't active?

Comment: But the boat sank from the first screenshot.

Comment: maybe they had planned to have a quest like that on the boat, they removed it before release for some reason, but forgot to remove all the photo triggers?